# Cannot get back to previous interface

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

This is my first interface using a button to call another xib interface

```
-(IBAction)poli

UIViewController *ll = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:ll animated:YES];
```

and second interface calling the previous one ....

```
-(IBAction)popaa

UIViewController *ui = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ra" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:ui animated:YES];
```

but there occurs a  problem that shows

terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSUnknownKeyException`', reason: `[<UIViewController 0x7433230> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]`: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pol

could someone explain the problem, i just want the first xib to show the second and second to show the first xib via a button.

Comment: check your interface builder outlet connections

Comment: Have you checked your xib, all connections are present? More-over, why you're presenting modal view controller, if you want to pop, then just use:     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: Are you presenting the second controller from the first, and then presenting the first from the second? If so, this is not the way to do it. After presenting the second, you use dismissViewControllerAnimated: to dismiss the second controller, which takes you back to the first.'

Comment: @Mohit_Jaiswal: he is not using navigation controller. He is presenting view using present modal view controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152872/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-view)

Comment: @delmar i think your suggestion is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your xibs has any warning. Usually `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is thrown when you have added some view in xib but the same is not added to your class code or the outlet is not defined properly. In this case you have added some view `pol` to your xib but the same is not present in your `ll` or `ui` class.

Also your dismiss method should be,

```
- (IBAction)popaa

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: there are some presentmodalviewcontroller warning which is deprecated