# I have a textbox in xcode, and whenever I try to connect it to a property the app doesn't build

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a text box, and ctrl+clicked to the .h, and made an outlet and called it usernameTextField. So I'm not even typing out the property - xcode is doing it for me. Here is the text:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
```

When I try to run the program, it gives me this error -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<drawKitViewController 0x12fd0aff0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is 
not key value coding-compliant for the key usernameTextField.'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you change class in this view from UIView to your own class name?

Comment: Has this been connected twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152872/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-view) also.

Comment: JSA - nope, made sure of that.

sha - No, should I do that?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it's trying to instantiate standard UIView and that class has no idea about your usernameTextfield outlet.

Comment: okay I just cleaned the project and it works now. Sorry for wasting your time guys, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the class name for this class to your class name and not default `UIView`. Otherwise in runtime it tries to instantiate UIView class and bind all properties from interface builder to this class. And UIView has no idea about usernameTextField.