# Progress View update value error iOS

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to set the value of UIProgressView manually. I defined the outlet for it:

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

And set its value in one of my functions:

```
  [self.progressView setProgress:.5];
```

But I am getting this error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key progress line

Any body help me in this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152872/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-view) - read the answer posted by Joseph DeCarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet would be that your `progressView` is detached in the storyboard. Could you re-check if the connections are still there between your storyboard and .h file?
Or, if your .h file thinks that the connection is there but you may have accidentally deleted the progressView from the storyboard.

Comment: Connections are still there

Comment: If all connections are intact, could you do an OPTION+CLEAN (Clean build folder) and try building it again just to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for help. I deleted the progress bar and deleted connections and repeat the same progress. It starts working now.