# How to fix Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I made an app with `Table View` and `Segmented Control`, and this is my first time. I'm using some code and some tutorials, but It's not working. When I run my app It's crashing and it's showing this Error in logs:

> MyApplication[4928:336085] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
>   * First throw call stack:
>   (
>    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010516fd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105504deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010516f9c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
>    3   Foundation                          0x000000010364e19b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
>    4   UIKit                               0x0000000103c37d0c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
>    5   UIKit                               0x0000000103e6e7fb -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
>    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050a9890 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
>    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103e6d1de -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
>    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103c3e8d6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
>    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103c3f202 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
>    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103c3f560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
>    11  UIKit                               0x0000000103c3fcd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
>    12  UIKit                               0x000000010440b024 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
>    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103c0f5ca -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
>    14  UIKit                               0x0000000103c525bb -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4002
>    15  UIKit                               0x0000000103c5585c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489
>    16  UIKit                               0x0000000103c5536b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
>    17  UIKit                               0x00000001041feb8d __67-[UIStoryboardModalSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 243
>    18  UIKit                               0x00000001041ec630 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460
>    19  UIKit                               0x00000001041ec433 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
>    20  UIKit                               0x00000001041ec6f7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
>    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103aa6a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103c19e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>    23  UIKit                               0x0000000103c1a143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
>    24  UIKit                               0x0000000103c19263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>    25  UIKit                               0x0000000103b1999f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>    26  UIKit                               0x0000000103b1a6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>    27  UIKit                               0x0000000103ac5dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>    28  UIKit                               0x0000000103a9f553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
>    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105095301 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ + 17
>    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010508b22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010508a6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010508a0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>    33  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010726dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>    34  UIKit                               0x0000000103aa4f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
>    35  Dhikr                               0x0000000101f26282 main + 114
>    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001064c392d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The code that I used is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let foodList:[String] = ["Bread", "Meat", "Pizza", "Other"]
let drinkList:[String] = ["Water", "Soda", "Juice", "Other"]

@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        returnValue = foodList.count
        break
    case 1:
        returnValue = drinkList.count
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return returnValue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCells", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = foodList[indexPath.row]
        break
    case 1:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = drinkList[indexPath.row]
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return myCell
}

@IBAction func segmentedControlActionChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    myTableView.reloadData()  
}
```

Here is **main.Storyboard**

[image]

I checked the code many times, but it's not working. First I had to use only `Table View`, watching this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABVLSF3Vqdg) I thought it will work to use `Segmented Control` as in tutorial. But still doesn't work. Same code, same error.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152872/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-view

Comment: I faced a similar issue. The reason for that  was because I had made two schemes/targets for my app, and the view controller was added only in one of the schemes/targets and I was running the other target/scheme. Adding the Viewcontroller class to all the targets/schemes solved the issue.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have your storyboard set up to expect an outlet called `tableView` but the actual outlet name is `myTableView`.

If you delete the connection in the storyboard and reconnect to the right variable name, it should fix the problem.

Comment: How to "delete the connection"?

Comment: my word, do I have to click on the thing in the storyboard to see all the connections and delete them there? Is there some interface that shows me which things in storyboard are connected to which things in code? I have also heard of a ".nib" file which I have yet to find

Comment: @pete  The IBOutlet declarations in code will show you whether they are connected, but they won't show you which things in the storyboard are connected to variables that don't exist.

Comment: Right click on your button in the storyboard. Near the bottom, there will be an outlet shown. Click on the x next to it to remove it from the button.

Comment: A "Nib" file has an .xib file extension nowadays, so it is something of a misnomer

Answer (score 12):

Any chance that you changed the name of your table view from "tableView" to "myTableView" at some point?