# Swift generic table view data source and delegate, protocol backed NSManagedObjects, cannot obtain entity attribute, runtime error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics, core-data

**The Problem**

[image: break point screenshot]

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key active.'

Thanks to @GrahamPerks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812660/1883707) to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13793162/1883707), I inserted an exception breakpoint in my code, which now pauses execution at this line...

```
static var entityActive: Bool {
    return entity.value(forKey: "active") as! Bool // <-- PAUSES AT THIS LINE
}
```

This obviously needs further explanation...

**Background**

I'm writing a Core Data app that uses a generic table view data source and delegate, more or less set up per Florian Kugler's book "Core Data", published in 2017 by [objc.io](https://www.objc.io).

I have successfully linked three separate `UITableViewController`s to this generic data source / delegate. I am using a single main storyboard and these three controllers are linked to three `UISplitViewController` master/detail views.

I have deleted the automatically generated dataSource and delegate connections within the storyboard `UITableView`s (although whether I leave or remove these connections, seems to make no difference).

If I comment out the code for the `static var entityActive` above, the project will successfully Build and Run.

My code uses the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_, willDisplay:, forRowAt:)` to change the `.textColor` of text and `.backgroundColor` of cells, based on an attribute "active", stored as a boolean Scalar Type value with each entity.

For clarity, I'm trying to get the "active" attribute (every entity in my data model has a common attribute "active") for each `NSManagedObject` for the entity. The value of that "active" attribute (`Bool` `true` or `false`) for each entity is then used to format the cell in the if...else statement in the following code.

To attempt to maximise code reuse and minimise code repetition, I have also placed this delegate method in my generic data source / delegate class.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let entityObjectActive = T.entityActive

    if entityObjectActive == true {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    } else if entityObjectActive == false {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

}
```

The compiler doesn't complain.

I seem to be able to use the generic type `T` (representing Core Data entities) to associate the static property `entityActive` with my instance of `entityObjectActive` - so this seems to work...

```
let entityObjectActive = T.entityActive
```

To confirm, I have the following:

generic data source class....

```
class MyDataSource<T: Managed, 
                   Delegate: TableViewDataSourceDelegate>: 
                   NSObject, 
                   UITableViewDataSource, 
                   UITableViewDelegate, 
                   NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    // lots of code...
}
```

protocol...

```
protocol Managed: class, NSFetchRequestResult {
    static var entity: NSEntityDescription { get }
    static var entityActive: Bool { get } }
}
```

and extension...

```
extension Managed where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static var entity: NSEntityDescription { return entity()  }
    static var entityActive: Bool {
        return entity.value(forKey: "active") as! Bool
    }
}
```

**Attempts at Problem Solving**

I've done some reading attempting to resolve my problem, including a review of many blogs (on how to set up generics in general and generic table view data sources) and a lot of SO Q&A, in particular...

[How to fix Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266404/how-to-fix-error-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-table/36266503)

[Uncaught exception: This class is not key value coding-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353378/uncaught-exception-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)

[setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k/13812660#13812660)

It seems that all the SO Q&A are directly related to an issue with IB connections within storyboards. Maybe this is my issue too - but if that is the case it seems to me to be very well hidden.

Any assistance or advice please?

PS: I'm learning Swift after being a long time coder in Obj-C and I'm really struggling with the Generics Protocols Extensions paradigm shift, so it could be that my use of generic types is incorrect?

Comment: Are you sure you can access a static variable using key-value coding? Shouldn't it be accessed as `Managed.entity` when it's static?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your question but honestly I'm not sure, I'm new to Swift and generics, self taught on Obj-C and always preferred blocks to protocols in Obj-C, so part of my problem may be a general and basic lack of understanding of static variables, protocols and KVC. (PS tried your suggestion but could not make it work.)

Comment: Per your extension, `entity` is an `NSEntityDescription`: there's no `active` property for NSEntityDescriptions which is why you get the error.  Do you in fact mean to get the `active` attribute for the NSManagedObject?

Comment: @pbasdf correct, I'm trying to get the `active` attribute (every entity in my data model has a common `active` attribute) for the `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: I think your `entityActive` should not be static: it's a property of `Managed` objects, not the `Managed` class.  Your `willDisplayCell` code therefore needs to identify which `Managed` object is required - presumably using the `indexPath` to look up in the datasource.

Comment: Thanks for your input... after considering your comments, reading more and hacking some trial and error code, I've solved my problem. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those whose comments pointed me towards this solution...

My REVISED protocol `Managed`...

```
protocol Managed: class, NSFetchRequestResult {
    static var entity: NSEntityDescription { get }
    var attributeActive: Bool { get }  // <-- REMOVED static 
}
```

My REVISED extension of `Managed`...

***UPDATE - added `var attributeActive` to `Managed` extension...***

```
extension Managed where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static var entity: NSEntityDescription { return entity()  }

    var attributeActive: Bool {
         guard let attribute = self.value(forKey: "active") as? Bool else {
             return false // in case key "active" is not set
         }
         return attribute
    }
}
```

***UPDATE - deleted `var attributeActive` from managed object extensions as no longer required...***

<s>My REVISED extensions for each of my three Core Data Entities (the data of which is displayed in each of the three separate `UITableViewController`s)...</s>

```
extension <<DataModelEntity>>: Managed {    
    public var attributeActive: Bool {
        return self.active
    }

    @NSManaged public var active: Bool
    @NSManaged public var <<OTHER DATA MODEL ENTITY ATTRIBUTES>> //...
    // ...etc.
}
```

Maybe it is worth noting here for clarity that the **Codegen** value for each entity in the data model is set to **Manual/None**, so I have manually<sup>1</sup> prepared classes and extensions for each entity.

<sup>1</sup> When I write manually, I mean that I used the **Create Managed Object Subclass...** function under the **Editor** menu in Xcode and then manually entered my `Managed` protocol stubs.

Finally, my REVISED generic data source delegate class...

```
class MyDataSource<T: Managed, 
                   Delegate: TableViewDataSourceDelegate>: 
                   NSObject, 
                   UITableViewDataSource, 
                   UITableViewDelegate, 
                   NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    // lots of code...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let objectActive = object.attributeActive

        if objectActive == true {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        } else if entityObjectActive == false {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }

    // lots more code...

}
```

If anyone is still reading this essay, maybe you're interested in the reasons for this solution?

Frankly I'm still figuring out the details myself and plan to add a more concise / accurate reason in the future as my understanding improves regarding swift generics, protocols and extensions, but for now I provide the following...

As pointed out in comments, I was incorrectly attempting to get an entity property based on a data model attribute from an entity description. This is like trying to get the colour or size of a Lego brick by asking the Lego box for the characteristics of one of it's bricks. "Which brick?" might the box ask, if Lego boxes could ask such a thing.

Essentially I made a couple of errors. I didn't understand the effect the static definition had on my variables and I didn't properly understand how my `Managed` protocol and extension interacted with any classes that adopted that protocol.